# Ajax call from jquery to Jenkins job

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, jenkins, get

```
 var milestone_name = uiscripts.context.milestone.name;

    //AJAX block start
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://ctu-automation-server:8080/job/Check/build",
      type: "GET"
    });
    //AJAX block end
```

Above ajax call comes from a remote server to a Jenkins job on some other server. On running the script, I get this response:

```
GET https://ctu-automation-server:8080/job/Check/build 0 ()
```

I tried with POST operation too. If I do with http, it says the content must be served over https and thats why I replaced the URL with https.

Note: Jenkins job allows anonymous triggers and I could run it locally.

What is the cause of 0 response? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into CORS blocking your request; if you try this in FireFox you'll get a more useful error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my.jenkins.example.com/job/jobName/build. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

In browsers, requests to other websites are limited by CORS, for security reasons. See https://enable-cors.org/. You might try using this Jenkins plugin to allow requests from your website https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin